# Meteor: How to get Reactive Parent/Child dependency templates for Object attributes

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm working on a reactive dependence tree on Meteor (with Blaze), but I didn't found the best way to do it.

**First, the problem**

On this example I have container who set an `item` Object, who have an attribute `elements` (Array).

The `elements` attribute is loop, and a child template is loaded for every instance of it.

The element can be update on the child template, but the update isn't propagate to the container.

Also, I added an `Add` button to update the `item` ReactiveVar (from the `container`). Each field rendering is updated after `item` is updated on container, so the object as been updated but not re-rendered.

**HTML**

```
<template name="container">
  {{#let item=getItem}}
    <h1>Update {{item._id}}</h1>
    {{#each element in item.elements}}
      <div>
        {{> elementForm element}}
        <small>{{element.name}}</small>
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  {{/let}}
  <button name="add">Add</button>
</template>


<template name="elementForm">
  {{#let el=getEl}}
    <input value="{{el.name}}"/>
  {{/let}}
</template>
```

**Parent Template**

```
Template.container.onCreated(function onContainerCreated() {
  // From data
  let item = {
    _id: '123abc',
    elements: [
      {name: "El #1"},
      {name: "El #2"},
      {name: "El #3"},
    ]
  }
  // Create master ReactiveVar
  this.item = new ReactiveVar(item);
});

Template.container.helpers({
  getItem() {
    return Template.instance().item.get();
  },
});
Template.container.events({
  // Add a new element (Will refresh all elements render)
  'click button[name="add"]'(e) {
    let instance = Template.instance()
    let item = instance.item.get()
    item.elements.push({name: "new El"})
    instance.item.set(item)
  },
})
```

**Child template**

```
/* Element */
Template.elementForm.onCreated(function onElementCreated() {
  this.el = new ReactiveVar(this.data)
});
Template.elementForm.helpers({
  getEl() {
    return Template.instance().el.get()
  }
})
Template.elementForm.events({
  'change input'(e) {
    let instance = Template.instance()
    let el = instance.el.get()
    el.name = e.currentTarget.value
    instance.el.set(el)
  }
})
```

**Preview**

As meteor can't be integrate on Embed code, I make some images.

Default page

[image]

Update input didn't affect container render

[image]

Add a new item, will re render all the container and get new values

[image]

**Solution 1 ?** Send `item` ReactiveVar to the child

I know than sending the entire ReactiveVar to a child can be a solution to use the `.set()` method on the child.

But if I use this hack, I will have to send the entire `item` to each `elementForm` (not the best)

**Exemple**

```
/* Html */
<Template name="parentTemplate">
  <small>{{getFoo}}</small>
  {{> childTemplate getItem}}
</Template>
<Template name="childTemplate">
  <input value="{{getFoo}}" />
</Template>

/* Parent */
Template.parentTemplate.onCreated(function onParentCreated() {
  this.item = new ReactiveVar({ foo: bar})
});
Template.parentTemplate.helpers({
  getFoo() {
    return Template.instance().item.get().foo    
  },
  getItem() {
    return Template.instance().item // Send reactive var, net value (.get)
  }
})
/* Child */
Template.childTemplate.onCreated(function onChildCreated() {
  this.item = this.data.item // Use Parent Reactive var
});
Template.childTemplate.helpers({
  getFoo() {
    return Template.instance().item.get().foo    
  },
})
 Template.childTemplate.events({
  'change input'(e) {
    let item = Template.instance().item.get()   
    item.foo = e.currentTarget.value
    Template.instance().item.set(item) // Will update parent   
  },
})
```

**Solution 2 ?** Callback

An other solution is to send to the child template, in addition to element data, a callback for each action (like change) to inform the parent template to update the master ReactiveVar for a specific element.

**Example**

```
/* Html */
<Template name="parentTemplate">
  <small>{{getFoo}}</small>
  {{> childTemplate getData}}
</Template>
<Template name="childTemplate">
  <input value="{{getFoo}}" />
</Template>

/* Parent */
Template.parentTemplate.onCreated(function onParentCreated() {
  this.item = new ReactiveVar({ foo: bar})
});
Template.parentTemplate.helpers({
  getFoo() {
    return Template.instance().item.get().foo    
  },
  getData() {
    let instance = Template.instance()
    return {
      item: instance.item.get(),
      onChange: function(val) {
        // Update item here
        let item = instance.item.get()
        item.foo = val
        instance.item.set(item)
      }
    }
  }
})
/* Child */
Template.childTemplate.onCreated(function onChildCreated() {
});
Template.childTemplate.helpers({
  getFoo() {
    return Template.instance().data.item.foo    
  },
})
 Template.childTemplate.events({
  'change input'(e) {
    // Call parent callback
    Template.instance().data.onChange(e.currentTarget.value)  
  },
})
```

**Final Question**

What's the best way to handle Parent/Child Template to handle a list of element from a item object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually a good question.

IMHO depending on the case I mostly do kind of your solution 1.

Something like:

```
Template.container.onCreated(function(){
  //each elements are ReactiveVar
  let item = {
    _id: '123abc',
    elements: [
      {name: new ReactiveVar("El #1")},
      {name: new ReactiveVar("El #2")},
      {name: new ReactiveVar("El #3")},
    ]
  }
  // I don't wrap the wole item on a ReactiveVar if I don't need it.
});
```

Then, when you iterate on it with your `#each`, you will inject only the current element data into the datacontext of your child. From here, you can easily do:

```
Template.childTemplate.helpers({
  getName() {
    return this.name.get();    
  },
})
 Template.childTemplate.events({
  'change input'(e, tp) {
    newVal = e.currentTarget.value
    tp.currentData().name.set(newVal); 
  }
});
```

I used some "shortcut" as `Template.currentData()` and direct datacontext access on helper with `this.name.get()`.

You also can have direct access to the template instance as second parameter of an event:

```
'change input'(event, templateInstance) {}
```

I did not test it, I only give you the idea.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Do you code will update `item` on `container` even if you didn't have `ReactiveVar` on it ? Do you create one on child template ?

Comment: Why do you want to wrap item on reactiveVar? The only things you want to be updated are the element's data. So yes, in one sense you will have any time on your parent the according value of each child by their ReactiveVar.

Comment: Humm okay ! I missed the part where every elements are now `ReactiveVar`. It's working fine, but now the `item` object (a mongodb object in my case, using `meteor-astronomy` package) have no informations about update made on children tempalte. I think i'll use callback for intense parent/child template when it's for a Reactive Object (and not only a single var)

Comment: Then use meteor mongobd cursors at the place of every reactiveVar. In my case  I use reactiveVar only to store UI state (in a fancier way than using Session). Cursors are reactive too!

Comment: In my case it's a listing of nested elements on a Mongo Object. (Example (Users.emails = [ Emails ]) So I don't have cursor, and i'm using callback in my case, but it's good to know for more simple parent/child problem.